# line integrals and work

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

I was doing practice problems for vector calculus when I jumped into some confusion. The question asked to evaluate a line integral which is general taking the integral of the function then multiplied with the magnitude of the velocity function. 
However, when I looked at the solution, instead of taking the $\int f(t)|v(t)| dt$, it used the work equation $\int f(t).dr$.
What's the difference? How do I know to use $f.dr$ and $f(t)|v(t)|$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use mathjax to type.

Comment: They both are same.

Answer (score 1):

When you compute a line integral of the form
$$
\int_{C} f(x,y,z)\; dr
$$
on a line $C$, typically you need to find a parametrization of $C$ of the form
$$
\vec{r}(t)=x(t)\vec{i}+y(t)\vec{j}+z(t)\vec{k}, \quad t\in [a,b]
$$
So that you can re-express the integral in terms of the parameter $t$:
$$
\int_{C} f(x,y,z)\; dr = \int_a^b f(x(t),y(t),z(t))\;||\vec{r}'(t) ||\; dt
$$
So as mentioned by @mathlover, both integrals are equivalent, they are just not expressed in the same way.